# How do I render a sidebar inside of every template except index.hbs?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm building an ember app with Foundation and would like to render a sidebar on every template except index.hbs.

I feel like adding

```
{{partial 'sidebar'}}
```

to every template is probably not the best way. But Because I'm on a grid system and using a row with two colums, one for the content, one for the sidebar, I feel like this is the only way to get the sidebar into every template except the index template while also placing the sidebar in the same div as the main content.

It looks like this:

[image]

The template code here is:

```
<div class="row content">
  <div class="large-9 columns main-content">
    MAIN CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="large-3 columns sidebar">
    SIDEBAR
  </div>
</div>
```

So I want to the sidebar in every template except index but I also need it inside this div so as not to mess up the responsiveness. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a boolean property in your index route/controller.

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
   skipSidebar: true
});
```

Then, in your template

```
{{#unless skipSidebar}}
   {{partial 'sidebar'}}
{{/unless}}
```